# Paragraph after img won't expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with 3 h1 tags 3 img tags and 3 p tags
From the beginning every p tag is set to display:none;
I want when I click the h1 tag to expand(toggle) the p that follows after an img.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    *{text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        color: orange;

        font-family:Georgia;
        }
    img{
        display: inline-block;
        margin: auto;
        border:2px  solid black;
        border-radius: 21px 0px 21px 0px;
        background-color: black;

    }
    body{
        background-color: brown;
    }
    p{ 
        display: none;
        font-size: 24px;
    }
    h1:hover{
        background-color: black;
    }
    h1{
        border:2px solid blue;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
#top{box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 2px double #6495ED;
    background-color: #BCD2EE;
    height: 50px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#click{
    color: #eed5ad;
    border:0px;
}
#click:hover{background-color: transparent;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("h1").click(
            function(){
                $("> img >p",this).show();
            });
    });

</script>
    <title>Αξιοθέατα</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="click">Κάντε κλικ σε έναν νομό</h1>
<img src="http://www.golden-greece.gr/maps/kriti.jpg" usemap="#nomoi">
<map name="nomoi">
    <area shape="poly" coords="184,99,168,154,5,126,13,2,201,10," href="http://www.chania.gr/" alt="xania" target="new">
    <area shape="poly" coords="320,83,268,176,176,150,188,101,319,85,," href="http://www.rethimno.gr/" alt="rethimno" target="new">
    <area shape="poly" coords="448,117,432,140,464,201,281,227,271,179,273,172,287,166,293,144,305,150,320,132,315,118,324,88,330,81,351,91,444,117," href="http://www.heraklion.gr/" alt="heraklion" target="new">
    <area shape="poly" coords="632,115,631,195,467,204,450,118,509,104,539,149,569,138,629,115," href="http://www.lasithinews.gr/" alt="lasithi" target="new">
</map>
<h1>Ελούντα</h1><br>
<img src="http://says.gr/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%842.jpg" alt="Ελούντα" height="60%" width="60%">
<p>
    Η Ελούντα είναι ένα ψαροχώρι του νομού Λασιθίου στην βόρεια ακτή του νησιού της Κρήτης που αποτελεί μέρος του του Άγίου Νικολάου . Είναι παραθαλάσσιος και δημοφιλής τουριστικός προορισμός. Σε μεγάλο βαθμό την επισκέπτονται VIPs για τα παραθαλάσσια θέρετρα πολυτελείας . Απέναντι της βρίσκεται ένα νησί πόλυ μικρό που ονομάζεται Σπιναλόγκα που περικλείεται βόρεια από τον κόλπο της Ελούντας . Ο δρόμος πρός την Ελούντα από τον Άγιο Νικόλαο βρίσκεται περίπου 12 χιλιόμετρα σε μήκος ακολουθόντας την ακτή , καθώς ανεβαίνει προς την κορυφή ενός μικρού βουνού . Το μικρό χώριο της Πλάκας (Λασίθι) , με θέα το νησί της Σπιναλόγκας απέχει μόλις 5 χλμ. από την κεντρική πλατεία της Ελούντας κατευθυνόμενοι βόρεια μακριά από τον Άγιο Νικόλαο . Οι κάτοικοι της ζούσαν τις οικογένειές τους από τη γεωργία, το ψάρεμα, την παραγωγή αλατιού στις ενετικές αλυκές και την εξόρυξη της ακονόπετρας.
</p>
<h1>Ιστορία</h1>
<p>
    Στην Ελούντα οι πρώτες καταγράφες οικισμού ήταν η αρχαία πόλη της Ολούς της οποίας οι κάτοικοι ήταν σε σύγκρουση με τους κατοίκους της Ντοριαν Λατώ . Το μεγαλύτερο μέρος της Ολούς ήταν αναγεννημένο από την θάλασσα και είναι ακόμη ορατά τα σημάδια κατά την κατάδυση στον κόλπο της Ελούντας.  Άπο τις αρχές του 1900 έφευγαν άπο το λιμανάκι βαρκούλες που μετέφεραν τους λεπρούς στην κατοικία της Σπιναλόγκας .
</p>
<a href="#click">
<div id="top">
    Κορυφή
</div></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?
Here is a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/kounelios13/2f0nnsnn/

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird Everything you need is above.  This is the correct way to ask a question.

Comment: Can you change the html at all?  It would be much, much cleaner if you could put each "section" (heading, image, parargraph) into individual containers, such as divs.

Comment: I have to keep that structure

Comment: Can you clarify what you need then?  Currently `$("p").show();` will answer your question but I suspect there's more to it than that.

Comment: As you can see from my html I have an h1 tag.After an img tag and then a p tag.I want when I click an h1 tag to show or toggle the p tag that is after this h1 not every p tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply modify your js to be like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('p').eq(0).toggle();
    });
});
```

Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68zxjg7z/), please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `p` element after `img` in all case. I used [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/):

```
$("h1").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll("p:first").toggle();
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexChariz/y0amvw1c/7/)

Comment: You re right.I didn't check the jsfiddle before i comment